# I need someone help about python pandas module

Tags: python, pandas

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
input_path='d:\Desktop\lx' 
output_file='d:\Desktop\lx\output.xls'
all_workbooks=glob.glob(os.path.join(input_path,'melb*.xlsx'))
data_frames=[]
for workbook in all_workbooks:
    all_worksheets=pd.read_excel(workbook,sheet_name=None,index_col=None)
    workbook_total_sales=[]
    workbook_number_of_sales=[]
    worksheet_data_frames=[]
    worksheets_data_frames=None
    workbook_data_frame=None
    for worksheet_name,data in all_worksheets.items():
        total_sales=pd.DataFrame([float(str(value).strip('$').replace(',', ''))for value in data.loc[:,'Cost']]).sum()
        number_of_sales=len(data.loc[:,'Cost'])
        average_sales=pd.DataFrame(total_sales / number_of_sales)
        workbook_total_sales.append(total_sales)
        workbook_number_of_sales.append(number_of_sales)
     
        data={'workbook': os.path.basename(workbook),
              'worksheet': worksheet_name,
              'worksheet_total': total_sales,
              'worksheet_average': average_sales}
        worksheet_data_frames.append(pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['workbook','worksheet','worksheet_total','worksheet_average']))  # line 32 
    worksheets_data_frame=pd.concat(worksheet_data_frames,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
    workbook_total=pd.DataFrame(workbook_total_sales).sum()
    workbook_total_number_of_sales=pd.DataFrame(workbook_number_of_sales).sum()
    workbook_average=pd.DataFrame(workbook_total / workbook_total_number_of_sales)

    workbook_stats={'workbook':os.path.basename(workbook),'workbook_total':workbook_total,'workbook_average':workbook_average}
    workbook_stats=pd.DataFrame(workbook_stats,columns=['workbook','workbook_total','workbook_average'])
    workbook_data_frame=pd.merge(worksheets_data_frame,workbook_stats, on='workbook',how='left')
    data_frames.append(workbook_data_frame)
all_data_concatenated=pd.concat(data_frames,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(output_file)
all_data_concatenated.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='sums_and_averages',index=False)
writer.save()           `
```

Something is wrong at line 32:

```
worksheet_data_frames.append(pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['workbook','worksheet','worksheet_total','worksheet_average']))
```

The error I got：

```
runfile('D:/Desktop/lx/pandas.py', wdir='D:/Desktop/lx')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Desktop\lx\pandas.py", line 33, in <module>
    worksheet_data_frames.append(pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['workbook','worksheet','worksheet_total','worksheet_average']))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 435, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 254, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 69, in arrays_to_mgr
    arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 322, in _homogenize
    val = sanitize_array(

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 484, in sanitize_array
    subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 236, in asarray_tuplesafe
    values = [tuple(x) for x in values]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 236, in <listcomp>
    values = [tuple(x) for x in values]

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I don't know why.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the _full_ error message?

Comment: Thanks for you help. I've put the message on it.